# Django postgresql setup using 189Gig of ram and 144 core cpu fully with just a few users. How to debug?

Tags: django, postgresql, nginx, systemctl

Hey we are using Django + Postgresql with nginx to run our app. The problem is - as soon as there are few hundred users on the app; we start getting errors like :

```
 failed (24: Too many open files)
```

We have already increased our ulimit -Hn and ulimit -Sn.

I am also attaching a screenshot of htop
[image]
As you can see in the screenshot:
postgres is using too much CPU, which should not happen as we have a very powerful machine.
How can we debug the problem with postgresql with django?
By the way our max_connections are 700 and shared_buffers is 8080MB
What can we do next?

Comment: Can you share the code of view that triggers this issue? And model/manager concerned?

Comment: no specific view triggers this, as soon as there is generally a lot of users ( 1000~ concurrent users) , this happens.

Comment: Tune your queries so that they are faster, then they will use less CPU.

Comment: By tuning you mean use things like prefetch_related and select_related? Are there any more things to tune the queries?

Comment: No, by tuning Laurenz means that you have to improve the SQL that is used to get the data from the database. Better indexes, better datamodel, it can all help to improve performance. Do you have some results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for your slowest query? And the DDL (including indexes) for the tables involved in this query?

Comment: @PrashantPandey Without code, we cannot tell you anything... You have to analyze your code and find where there are the most queries triggered. Probably a big database table is not correctly joined when I see the size of postgres process maybe. Are you using cache?

Comment: @LucasGrugru I only have control over django ORM for postgresql not direct sql, in this case what can i do?

Comment: @PrashantPandey What I said can be applied with django ORM. There are many plugins for analyzing queries. Finding a query without prefetching or selecting_related is not very hard. You have to look at your code line by line. With a focus on the big table as I said. And you do not respond about cache ?

Comment: @LucasGrugru Thanks i will check the part about analyzing queries. And no we do not use any cache.